# Handle multiple key value filtering url in Jersey Rest API

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I am implementing filtering, sorting and paging functionality with Jersey Rest API, I've already done sorting and paging like this:

```
www.example.com/users?sort=firstname&sortOder=asc&page=1&per_page=10
```

Now I have to implement filter, which should filter data based on each columns search term and I should be able to get all the parameters together, this is a general example:

```
www.example.com/users?sort=firstname&sortOder=asc&page=1&per_page=10&firstname=somekeyword&lasname=somekeyword
```

Please note firstname and lastname are keys, which are column names, the bad thing about this is that I have to get each param one by one, which prevents the application to be dynamic and also filter keys are not encapsulated, it should look like this:

```
www.example.com/users?sort=firstname&sortOder=asc&page=1&per_page=10&filter={firstname:somekeyword, lasname:somekeyword}
```

Please note I don't want it to be JSON, it is just an example.

I've tried `@Context UriInfo ui;` and `@MatrixParam`, but it looks like I could not find a clear solution for this.

Comment: 1) "which prevents the application to be dynamic" what do you mean exactly? Do you want to add new filter values without editing Java-Classes?
2) "filter keys are not encapsulated" where is this important for you? In Java? In this URL?
3) "I don't want it to be JSON": how should the URL look like?

Comment: 1) "which prevents the application to be dynamic" this means I need to get filter parameters in one variable, not one by one. 2) "filter keys are not encapsulated" this is important because if you check the second url in the question, "firstname" is just a general parameter and does not belong to filter parent. Yes it is Java and Jersey framework Rest API as you can see from the tags. 3) that is what I am interested in, how can i design url for this purpose.

Comment: Yes I know that this is Java/Jersey ;) I asked you, where you want to encapsulate the filter keys. There is an easy/common solution to encapsulate it in Java-Classes and there is no general solution for URLs. And because there is no general solution, I asked you for a format you want. And maybe it would help to understand what you want, if you show what you tried already.

Comment: Now I am thinking I will do it as I have it in the first example url. I have the User class, which contains all the fields, so I can validate url params by comparing its keys to User class fields.